# How can I prove that $x^5+x^4+3$ can't be null?

Tags: functions, polynomials

How can I prove that  :
The function $$f(x)=x^5+x^4+3$$ can't be null

I cannot fin how the solve this exercise i tried to factorize but i get nothing

Comment: Try plotting it!

Comment: @AngeloRendina Plotting usually doesn't count as a proof $\ddot\frown$

Comment: @SimpleArt aren't we supposed to give hints, rather than solutions?

Comment: @AngeloRendina No, proof is explicitly asked, isn't it?

Comment: Any real polynomial of **odd degree** has at least one real root. Either you miscopied the polynomial or the claim is false.

Comment: I don't have a full proof but all polynomial a are continuous and differentiate everywhere so it can't be null

Comment: @Simple, just because someone asks for a proof, doesn't necessarily mean that giving a proof is the best course of action. Often much better to give the person what he/she needs to construct a proof.

Comment: By null, do you mean it is not identically zero or it does not have any $x$ for which it is zero? For the first, just say $f(0)=3$ and you are done. That is what I would understand about a function being null.  If you want to show there is no $x$ for which $f(x)=0$ you need to specify what is the domain, the set of allowable values for $x$.  If $x$ can range over the reals the claim is false.  There is a root with $x$ a little below $-1.5$.  If $x$ has to be rational, the rational root theorem shows there are no rational (integral) roots.

Answer (score 4):

If the question is to prove that $f(x)\ne0$ for any real value of $x$, then as DonAntonio has already noted, there is no proof because the assertion is false.

As Aaron M has noted, all polynomials are continuous, and since for the given function, $f(-2) = -13$ and $f(-1) = 3$, there clearly is at least one root somewhere between $-2$ and $-1$.